# How can I send updated object from subdocument array of objects using mongoose as response

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to send updated object as response from subdocument.

From my carts model, I am querying the subdocument array which is cartItems. After querying and doing crud operation, I don't want to send the full cartItems array as response. I want to send the updated object as response.

```js
exports.removeCartItem = async (req, res) => {
  const { itemId } = req.params
  const { email } = req.user
  const { id } = req.body

  const targetUser = await User.findOne({ email }).exec()

  const cartItemRemoved = Cart.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      user: targetUser._id,
    },
    {
      $pull: { cartItems: { _id: itemId } },
    },
    { new: true },
  ).exec((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(er)
    }
    res.json(data)
  })
}
```

This is the response I am getting right now:

```
{
  "user": "621def0665c08eff01794f6e",
  "cartItems": [
    {
      "product": "6228edb603d5e7ca773a2b04",
      "quantity": 5,
      "price": 200,
      "_id": "622b04741bab0093c963ef18"
    }
  ],
  "_id": "622b04741bab0093c963ef17",
  "__v": 0
}
```

I want send the updated object as response - something like below:

```
{
     "product":"6228edb603d5e7ca773a2b04",
      "quantity": 5,
      "price": 200,
      "_id": "622b04741bab0093c963ef18"
}
```

Comment: how about using -> res.json(data.cartItems.filter((item) => item.id===itemId));